# (Javascript) Trying to allow a key press only once in hangman game when it is deemed to be incorrect

Tags: javascript

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can add to help make my problem more clear!

Im trying to get my hangman game to not allow another key press of the same kind if it is deemed to be incorrect. Once a key press is deemed incorrect it is shown on screen as an incorrect guess and I don't want it to be shown more than once or to count as another incorrect guess as guesses are limited.
Here's a link to my site: https://thy-turk.github.io/Word-Guess-Game/

Here is the code I've been trying to manipulate to allow this.

```
//if else comparing letter guessed with the current word
if (letterPos.length) {
   for(i = 0; i < letterPos.length; i++) {
         currentWord[letterPos[i]] = lettersGuessed;
   }
   document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");
} else {
   // if (lettersGuessed.includes(letter)) {
   //     return;
   // }
   document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed + " ";
   guessesLeft--;
   document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;
}
```

The stuff I have commented out is the attempt I kept coming back to, but could never make work.
I know the way I've set this up is less than ideal. I've tried using functions throughout, but just ended up breaking everything.

Here is the entirety of the code for reference.

```js
var currentWord = [];
var answerWord = [];
var lettersReset = "";
var i;
var guessesLeft = 15;

// Array for the word bank of possible answers
var wordAnswers = ["vapor", "wave", "keyboard", "javascript", "coding", "practice", "technology", "hangman", "retro", "internet", "lamborgini", "ferrari", "cellphone", "computer", "headphones", "speakers", "vinyl", "record"];

// Math function to randomly pick a word from the wordbank
var answer = wordAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordAnswers.length)];

// Variable that counts the number of guesses left
document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

// Variable that counts the number of wins
var wins = 0;
document.getElementById("num-of-wins").innerHTML = wins;

// Loop that creates empty spaces for the words
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
  currentWord.push("_");
}
document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");

//Function that will evaluate the position of a letter in the word
function wordLetters(letter) {
  var letterPos = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    if (answer[i] === letter)
      letterPos.push(i);
  }
  return letterPos;
}

//Return letters that arent guessed still
function lettersToGuess() {
  var i;
  var toGuess = 0;
  for (i in currentWord) {
    if (currentWord[i] === "_")
      toGuess++;
  }
  return toGuess;
}

//Function to capture user input
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var letter = event.key.toLowerCase();
  var lettersGuessed = letter;
  var i;
  var letterPos = wordLetters(lettersGuessed);
  console.log(letter);


  //if else comparing letter guessed with the current word
  if (letterPos.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < letterPos.length; i++) {
      currentWord[letterPos[i]] = lettersGuessed;
    }
    document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");
  } else {
    // if (lettersGuessed.includes(letter)) {
    //     return;
    // }
    document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed + " ";
    guessesLeft--;
    document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;
  }

  // If user correctly guesses word the game is reset
  if (lettersToGuess() == 0) {
    guessesLeft = 15;
    document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

    document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = lettersReset;

    answer = wordAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordAnswers.length)];

    currentWord = [];
    for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
      currentWord.push("_");
    }
    document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");

    wins++;
    document.getElementById("num-of-wins").innerHTML = wins;
  }

  //Resets game if out of guesses
  if (guessesLeft === 0) {
    guessesLeft = 15;
    document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;
    document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = lettersReset;

    answer = wordAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordAnswers.length)];

    currentWord = [];
    for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
      currentWord.push("_");
    }
    document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Press any key to get started!</h1>
<br />

<div class="container">

  <p>Wins: </p>
  <p><span id="num-of-wins"></span></p><br />

  <p>Current Word: </p><br />
  <p><span id="active-word"></span></p>

  <p>Number of guesses remaining: </p><br />
  <p><span id="guesses-remain"></span></p><br />

  <p>Letters already Guessed: </p><br />
  <p><span id="letters-guessed"></span></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I'm gonna put my edited version of your code at the bottom and do the explaining up here.

First, you needed somewhere to keep track of the letters that you had already pressed. I added an array at the top of your script section to keep everything together. This is also important because it is outside the scope of the keyup event

[image]

Second, I actually added a little quality of life change in there. You weren't checking if the button pressed was actually a letter so I fixed that by wrapping everything in an if statement and then checking for the letter codes.

[image]

Then finally all were doing is using the `includes()` function. That's gonna check if the letter that was pressed has been seen already. If it has we do nothing. If it hasn't then we'll push that letter into the pastLetters array so that if we see it again we don't punish the user for it. Since the pastLetters array if in the parent scope of this it's persistent and won't be overridden if there's another keydown event.

[image]

Also important to note! I added that array to your reset pieces too so that when the game gets reset, the pastLetters array also gets reset.

[image]

```js
var currentWord = [];
var answerWord = [];
// Making an array to put the letters that we've already seen into.
var pastLetters = [];
var lettersReset = "";
var i;
var guessesLeft = 15;

// Array for the word bank of possible answers
var wordAnswers = ["vapor", "wave", "keyboard", "javascript", "coding", "practice", "technology", "hangman", "retro", "internet", "lamborgini", "ferrari", "cellphone", "computer", "headphones", "speakers", "vinyl", "record"];

// Math function to randomly pick a word from the wordbank
var answer = wordAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordAnswers.length)];

// Variable that counts the number of guesses left

document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

// Variable that counts the number of wins
var wins = 0;
document.getElementById("num-of-wins").innerHTML = wins;

// Loop that creates empty spaces for the words
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
  currentWord.push("_");
}
document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");

//Function that will evaluate the position of a letter in the word
function wordLetters(letter) {
  var letterPos = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    if (answer[i] === letter)
      letterPos.push(i);
  }
  return letterPos;
}

//Return letters that arent guessed still
function lettersToGuess() {
  var i;
  var toGuess = 0;
  for (i in currentWord) {
    if (currentWord[i] === "_")
      toGuess++;
  }
  return toGuess;
}

//Function to capture user input
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  // Checking to make sure that the key pressed is actually a letter.
  if ((event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) || event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122) {
    var letter = event.key.toLowerCase();
    var lettersGuessed = letter;
    var i;
    var letterPos = wordLetters(lettersGuessed);

    //if else comparing letter guessed with the current word
    if (letterPos.length) {
      for (i = 0; i < letterPos.length; i++) {
        currentWord[letterPos[i]] = lettersGuessed;
      }
      document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");
    } else {
      // If the letter has already been seen don't do it again.
      if (!pastLetters.includes(letter)) {
        // Placing the letter into an array that we can reference outside the scope of the key up event.
        pastLetters.push(letter);
        document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed + " ";
        guessesLeft--;
        document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;
      }
    }

    // If user correctly guesses word the game is reset
    if (lettersToGuess() == 0) {
      guessesLeft = 15;
      document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

      document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = lettersReset;

      answer = wordAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordAnswers.length)];

      currentWord = [];
      pastLetters = [];
      for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        currentWord.push("_");
      }
      document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");

      wins++;
      document.getElementById("num-of-wins").innerHTML = wins;

    }

    //Resets game if out of guesses
    if (guessesLeft === 0) {
      guessesLeft = 15;
      document.getElementById("guesses-remain").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

      document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = lettersReset;

      answer = wordAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordAnswers.length)];

      currentWord = [];
      pastLetters = [];
      for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        currentWord.push("_");
      }
      document.getElementById("active-word").innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Press any key to get started!</h1>
<br />

<p>Wins: </p>
<p><span id="num-of-wins"></span></p><br />

<p>Current Word: </p><br />
<p><span id="active-word"></span></p>

<p>Number of guesses remaining: </p><br />
<p><span id="guesses-remain"></span></p><br />

<p>Letters already Guessed: </p><br />
<p><span id="letters-guessed"></span></p>
```

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of images of it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought since I posted the code at the bottom it wouldn't have mattered.

Comment: Also: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)